# Blender 2.80 Beta wierd vewport behavior

Tags: 3d-view

I have a model about 83mm wide that I am working on, I can't zoom in too close to it because the viewport chops part of the model even though I am not zoomed all the way into it. Does anyone by chance know why it is doing this and is there a setting I can change to fix it?

Thanks
[image]

Comment: If you select the object and press the period key on numpad, does it fix the issue?

Comment: It doesn't. Same behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Issue is Clipping related, at a certain distance surfaces can't get drawn. Imagine the camera as a "plane" that you're moving into the Object. Whats infront, gets shown, whats behind is occluded.

To fix this issue it is recommended to change the units you use in Blender. You can find them in the Properties Editor -> Scene -> Units :

[image]

By default this value should be at "1.000"
 - Change it to "0.1"
You will notice no change, except a change in the "numeric" size of your model. [image]

After this, you scale up your model by a factor of 10, the model is "bigger" but still has the desired measurements and has no visibility issues.

Comment: That did it, I had the units but not the unit scale. thanks!